# Could anyone please make me understand 'the solution' to 'this question' from Set-Theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is the question:

> Suppose $A_1, A_2, \ldots A_{30}$
> are thirty sets each with five elements and $B_1, B_2, \ldots B_n$ are $n$ sets each with three elements. Let $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{30} A_{i}= \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{n} B_{j}=S$. Assume that each element of $S$ belongs to exactly ten of $A_i$s and exactly 9 of $B_j$s. Find $n$.

And this is the solution:

> Since each $A_i$ has $5$ elements and each element of $S$ belongs to exactly $10$ of $A_i$s.
>
> $$\therefore S=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{30} A_{i} \implies n(S) = 1/10 \sum\limits_{i=1}^{30} n(A_i) =1/10(5\cdot 30)=15 \tag{1}$$
>
> Again, each $B_j$ has $3$ elements and each element of $S$ belongs to exactly 9 of $B_j$s.
>
> $$\therefore S=\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{n} B_{j} \implies n(S) = 1/9 \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} n(B_j) =1/9(3n)=n/3. \tag{2} $$
>
> From (1) and (2) , we get : $15=n/3 \implies n=45$.

These are my queries:

- I know i have to find the missing value of $n$ but what is that $15$ in equation (1)?
- Is $15$ the number of elements that $S$ can get from union of $30$ sets of $A_i$ which has $5$ elements each?
- Or is it the number of sets that $S$ got from union of 30 sets of $A_i$?
- What actually does equation (1) shows?
- Does $n(S)$ in equation (1) tells us the number of elements that we will get by summing up $30$ sets of $A_i$?
- Why, in equation (1), sum of $30$ sets has been divided by $10$?

The answer is kind of confusing. Can you please break it up into pieces so that I can understand it better and not rote learn it?

Same questions are in my mind for equation number (2) too.

Source to the above query...

(Example 10) in the below image...

https://html2-f.scribdassets.com/6gpetzns1s411zkf/images/15-d1cd7fba0c.jpg

Please do answer my question. I tried my best to understand it but couldn't.

Also it took me around 90 minutes to frame it on Stackexchange.

Comment: Equations (1) and (2) arise from overcounting arguments: when you sum the sizes (cardinalities) of the 30 sets $A_i$, you get $30\cdot 5$, but you've overcounted each element of $S$ by a factor of 10. Hence the size of $S$ is a tenth of 150, which is $15$. Equation (2) uses similar reasoning to deduce another number equal to the size of $S$. Setting these two numbers equal allows you to solve for the value of $n$.